# Spring Security with JDBC Annotation only

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller, jdbc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot Application using the Spring Security. I took the following example from http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/. They use an "In Memory Authentification". I want to do the same but use a JDBC-Authentification.

Here is my **WebSecurityConfig** class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select * from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select * from user_roles where username=?");
    }
}
```

I also set up a MySQL Database *"test"* and two tables *"users"* and *"user_roles"*.
When I run the application and try to sign in I dont't get any Exceptions, but the application somehow can't find the user.

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

**Login page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-securing-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::security[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::security[] -->

        <!-- JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: For starters your queries are wrong, the one for users must return 3 columns (username, password and enabled) and the one for authorities 2 (username, role). Now it returns whatever you put in there. Also why on earth do you have spring-jdbc version 3.2.8 in your dependencies? You are now mixing spring version, just add the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` to get the  dependency you need (or at least remove the version tag).

Answer (score 1):

Your user has to have at least one role assigned. If the user has no role, then the authentication fails (even if you want to be able to login without any specific roles). Also make sure, that the `enabled` flag of the user is true.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that your Datasource is solved as a separated Bean instead of instantiate it in your configureGlobal Method:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // create and return a new JDBC DataSource ...
}
```

You can make use the Bean as you made in your configureGlobal Method:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
```

Comment: What is than your Stacktrace eg. Log saying?